# Xamarin.Forms: Error Specified cast is not valid when using Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I thought I had fixed this, but it doesn't seem to be working anymore. I have a picker that looks like this:

```
                        <StackLayout Padding="15">
                            <Label Text="Choose a Victory"
                                   FontSize="Subtitle"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   TextColor="{StaticResource TitleFontColour}"
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource MontSerrat}"/>
                            <Picker x:Name="quickPicker" 
                                    Title="- Select -"
                                    TitleColor="White"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    TextColor="#8759D7"
                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource MontSerrat}"
                                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Desc}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDesc}">
                            </Picker>
                        </StackLayout>
```

The picker is based on:

```
        public Task<List<QuickVictories>> GetQuickVictoriesAsync()
        {
            return _database.Table<QuickVictories>().OrderByDescending(x => x.DisplaySeq).ToListAsync();
        }
```

My Model is:

MainModel.cs

```
    public class QuickVictories
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength (140)]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int DisplaySeq { get; set; }
    }
```

My look behind AddVictory.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            quickPicker.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetQuickVictoriesAsync();
        }

        async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var selectedQuickVictory = quickPicker.SelectedItem as QuickVictories;
            var quickVictory = selectedQuickVictory.Desc;

            var victory = new TheVictory()
            {
                Title = title.Text ?? quickVictory ?? "No title",
                Quick = quickVictory ?? "N/A",
                Details = details.Text ?? "No details were entered.",
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            await App.Database.SaveVictoryAsync(victory);

            await DisplayAlert(
                "You have just celebrated a Victory!",
                "Your Victory has been saved for future celebrations.",
                "Woohoo!"
            );

            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

Whenever I try to save using OnSaveButtonClicked I get the error specifically on this line:
`var quickVictory = selectedQuickVictory.Desc;`

This method is currently working on my production version of the app that is live in the Google Play store, so I am very confused about why this isn't working anymore.

Does anyone have any idea where I can look to try and fix this because I'm fresh out of ideas.

The goal, to be clear, is that I get the Desc from the QuickVictories model. I have tried casting the object to string, but it doesn't seem to be working since moving to the picker being the return of a sqlite query.

Edit:

Uploading a pic of the SelectedItem debug.

[SelectedItem Debug Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pNXP.png)

Comment: that doesn't make sense because there is no cast on that line.  If you look in the debugger what is the **actual type** of `quickPicker.SelectedItem`?

Comment: @Jason It's an object. I know there's no Cast there, and I think I may have confused things: I have tried casting before (i.e. var selectedQuickVictory = (string)quickPicker.SelectedItem;) but I that stopped working as soon as the picker used the output of a SQLite query instead of using a static list I generated, I have no idea why.

Comment: So are you getting an exception/error, or is it just "not working"?  The debugger should show you the actual type, not just object.

Comment: The error is: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I've added an image of the message I get when hovering over SelectedItem. I believe it is an object, as most posts/tutorials I've looked at says I need to cast it to a string, as that's what I want to save it as. But it just... Isn't working. The method you see in the above post is currently working in a production version of the app that's available on the Play store, and it seems to work. I'm just so confused about why this isn't working anymore.

Comment: SelectedItem will be null if nothing has been selected.  Are you sure that you have selected a picker item?  You should probably also get rid of `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDesc}"`

Comment: So that's not required? It can be null, which is why I set it to "N/A" if it's null. There's one bit of understanding I'm missing here and it's just not clicking. How do I handle it being null?

Comment: test for it - `if (picker.SelectedItem == null)` then display a message telling the user they need to pick something.  Or programmatically set it to a default value.  Or whatever makes sense

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: That has worked. How can I mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if `SelectedItem` is null

```
if (picker.SelectedItem == null)
```

and display a message to the user, or whatever is appropriate for your use case